# How to get Youtube video categories using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning about YouTube web scraping. I can get the video title, subscribers, etc. Now I want to get the video category, here we can see that the video category is gaming, I want to get the 'gaming' value. Then, I also want to get the 'Grand Theft Auto VI' value.

[Scraping Category and the name of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToU3y.png)

Below is a snippet of the html or DOM element.

```
<div id="contents" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-row-renderer"><ytd-rich-metadata-renderer class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-row-renderer" rounded="" component-style="RICH_METADATA_RENDERER_STYLE_BOX_ART"><!--css-build:shady--><!--css-build:shady--><a id="endpoint-link" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer" href="/channel/UCGGLvMdJjEz_tol-LMrfE_w">
  <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer"><template is="dom-if"></template></dom-if>
  
    <div id="thumbnail" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">
      <yt-img-shadow class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer no-transition" loaded="" style="background-color: transparent;"><!--css-build:shady--><!--css-build:shady--><img id="img" draggable="false" class="style-scope yt-img-shadow" alt="" width="72" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/EtfzhlZIV-MXUa8FV4txiWlh-Fm02NXxJ6TlR_27TFUgNTUJxb-UBPjgkTMG95uWj-RKGdzwPw=s100-w72-h100-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-nd-rj"></yt-img-shadow>
    </div>
  <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer"><template is="dom-if"></template></dom-if>
  <div id="text-container" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">
    <div id="title" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">Grand Theft Auto VI</div>
    <div id="subtitle" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">
      2025
    </div>
    <ytd-badge-supported-renderer id="badges" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer" disable-upgrade="" hidden="">
    </ytd-badge-supported-renderer>
    <div id="call-to-action" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">
      <div class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">Browse game</div>
      <yt-icon class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer"><!--css-build:shady--><!--css-build:shady--><yt-icon-shape class="style-scope yt-icon"><icon-shape class="yt-spec-icon-shape"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; fill: currentcolor;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" focusable="false" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><path d="m9.4 18.4-.7-.7 5.6-5.6-5.7-5.7.7-.7 6.4 6.4-6.3 6.3z"></path></svg></div></icon-shape></yt-icon-shape></yt-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="information-button-container" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer" hidden=""></div>
</a>
</ytd-rich-metadata-renderer><ytd-rich-metadata-renderer class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-row-renderer" rounded="" component-style="RICH_METADATA_RENDERER_STYLE_TOPIC"><!--css-build:shady--><!--css-build:shady--><a id="endpoint-link" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer" href="/gaming">
  <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer"><template is="dom-if"></template></dom-if>
  
    <div id="thumbnail" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">
      <yt-img-shadow class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer no-transition" loaded="" style="background-color: transparent;"><!--css-build:shady--><!--css-build:shady--><img id="img" draggable="false" class="style-scope yt-img-shadow" alt="" width="96" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/QqoTjrpKRDMfGFPYpgIaTmHkbQ6Lk-brN77OxCYwl0jTtluavivXDdd4lR2wQsr_hcIggw=s136-w136-h136-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-nd-rj"></yt-img-shadow>
    </div>
  <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer"><template is="dom-if"></template></dom-if>
  <div id="text-container" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">
    <div id="title" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">Gaming</div>
    <div id="subtitle" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer" hidden="">
      
    </div>
    <ytd-badge-supported-renderer id="badges" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer" disable-upgrade="" hidden="">
    </ytd-badge-supported-renderer>
    <div id="call-to-action" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">
      <div class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer">Browse all gaming</div>
      <yt-icon class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer"><!--css-build:shady--><!--css-build:shady--><yt-icon-shape class="style-scope yt-icon"><icon-shape class="yt-spec-icon-shape"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; fill: currentcolor;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" focusable="false" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><path d="m9.4 18.4-.7-.7 5.6-5.6-5.7-5.7.7-.7 6.4 6.4-6.3 6.3z"></path></svg></div></icon-shape></yt-icon-shape></yt-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="information-button-container" class="style-scope ytd-rich-metadata-renderer" hidden=""></div>
</a>
</ytd-rich-metadata-renderer></div>
```

I use the some of this code below.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#endpoint-link .yt-simple-endpoint')
cat = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#text-container .style-scope .ytd-rich-metadata-renderer').text
print(cat)
```

The second one also error :

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#contents .style-scope .ytd-rich-metadata-renderer')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
container = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#text-container .style-scope .ytd-rich-metadata-renderer')
print(container)
game_name = container.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#title .style-scope .ytd-rich-metadata-renderer').text
print(game_name)
```

The error i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Portfolio\Web Scrapping\scrapingprojects\lul.py", line 103, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#endpoint-link .yt-simple-endpoint')
  File "D:\Portfolio\Web Scrapping\scrapingprojects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Portfolio\Web Scrapping\scrapingprojects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Portfolio\Web Scrapping\scrapingprojects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#endpoint-link .yt-simple-endpoint"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.225); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

Now, I hope this explanation can be understood. I really want to know how, and have spent many hours trying to find the error. Please help. Thank You. BTW, I also want to get the release date value, which is '2025'. This is a video trailer for GTA VI

Comment: Assuming that you just want to retrieve information about a channel and its videos, playlists etc (and not actually want to learn scraping), you might want to consider using the [YouTube official API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs)

Answer (score 1):

That information is embed in one of the `script` tags in the source code.

You could either:

- Get the JSON object that is inside of one of the `script` tags and get the value, or
- Search the following item: `<meta itemprop="genre" content="Gaming">` inside the source code of the video/page

It's up to you to choose which option is more easy to use.